# Architecting Bloc and StreamControllers to handle events

Tags: flutter

I'm building a Flutter app using BLoCs. I have a view where I send multiple events to the bloc and also streams data to the view.

Currently, I have different sinks I'm adding to depending on what the user is doing e.g. clicking a radio button, clicking a button to increase a counter, all in the same view. I'm searching how to handle these events in a common sink as it seems like a lot of plumbing to have a sink for each part. When I'm changing state I use different streams it's, but it's for the event handling part I'm looking around for a solution.

Any guidance to make the sink handling cleaner or is this the way to do it?

example of the current code I would like to streamline

```
// distance
  StreamController<bool> _cmdDistanceController = StreamController<bool>();
  StreamSink get distanceCommands => _cmdDistanceController.sink;

  StreamController<String> _syncDistanceController =
      StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  Stream<String> get syncDistances => _syncDistanceController.stream;

  // speed
  StreamController<bool> _cmdSpeedController = StreamController<bool>();
  StreamSink get speedCommands => _cmdSpeedController.sink;

  StreamController<String> _syncSpeedController =
      StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  Stream<String> get syncSpeed => _syncSpeedController.stream;
```

Comment: `"or is this the way to do it"` - post some code of `"this"`

Comment: I've updated with some code. it's the _cmdXXX controllers I would like to merge into a single controller in some smart way. Besides what you see above I have 3 more for other inputs in the same wiew

Comment: hmmm, i dont quite understand what you mean by "merge" but maybe its `StreamGroup` you are looking for? the docs say: *"A collection of streams whose events are unified and sent through a central stream."*

Comment: Ohhh haven't heard of StreamGroup, but yes central is what I'm looking for. A central sink I can use instead of exposing two. This would require I add something else than bool

Comment: a stream ID (indicating the type of command) or something?

Comment: hmm can't see how this would reduce the number of streams for input. I was thinking more of a "Command" like approach. maybe its just my background and I'm new to flutter and dart

Comment: With a commandId I could just use a regular stream and a single sink as input. Just seems a bit lowlevel to be switching in the listener to determine the change and handling